# Tool for testing syslog

Tags: syslog

Does anyone know of a tool or a script that I could use to send messages to syslog? I'm trying to troubleshoot a syslog configuration, and I'm having trouble eliminating possibilities. What I would like to do is something like this:

```
./testScript -f myFacility "testing testing 123"
```

and it sends it to syslog on the local machine.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Rich

Answer (score 25, accepted):

have a look at the [**logger**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) command.

e.g.

`logger -p auth.notice "Some message for the auth.log file"`